# Subscribing to BLE notifications with flutter_reactive_ble throws error?

Tags: swift, flutter, dart, bluetooth

I'm pretty new to Dart and know nothing about Swift. Trying to use the flutter_reactive_ble package to manage the BT side of an app I'm building. So far things are going smooth up to the point where attempting to enable notifications fails and crashes the app.

The problem occurs when trying to call `subscribeToCharacteristic` method like this:

```
class MeshProxyRx extends ReactiveState<Uint8List> {
  MeshProxyRx(this._ble);

  final FlutterReactiveBle _ble;
  final _stateStreamController = StreamController<Uint8List>.broadcast();

  StreamSubscription _meshProxyDataOut;

  Uint8List rxDataBuffer;

  @override
  Stream<Uint8List> get state => _stateStreamController.stream;

  startNotification(_proxyDevice) {
    print('Notification Start');

    final characteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
        serviceId: serviceUuid,
        characteristicId: characteristicUuid,
        deviceId: _proxyDevice);

    _meshProxyDataOut =
        _ble.subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic).listen((data) {
      rxDataBuffer.addAll(data);
      _stateStreamController.add(rxDataBuffer);
      // code to handle incoming data
      // ProxyNodeNotify(nodeAddress: [0x18, 0x28]);
      print(data);
    }, onError: (dynamic error) {
      // code to handle errors
      print('Start Notification returns Error: $error');
    });
  }

  Future<void> closeStream() async {
    await _stateStreamController.close();
  }

  Future<void> closeSubscription() async {
    _meshProxyDataOut?.cancel();
  }
}
```

The error that throws is:

```
flutter: REACTIVE_BLE: Start connecting to device with arguments (deviceId: 5523499D-8846-A794-F350-1B5E258859F3, servicesWithCharacteristicsToDiscover: null, timeout: null)
flutter: REACTIVE_BLE: Received ConnectionStateUpdate(deviceId: 5523499D-8846-A794-F350-1B5E258859F3, connectionState: DeviceConnectionState.connected, failure: null)
flutter: Notification Start
flutter: REACTIVE_BLE: Start subscribing to notifications for QualifiedCharacteristic(characteristicId: 2ade, serviceId: 1828, deviceId: 5523499D-8846-A794-F350-1B5E258859F3)
Assertion failed: file flutter_reactive_ble/PluginController.swift, line 103
Assertion failed: file flutter_reactive_ble/PluginController.swift, line 103
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Assertion failed
    frame #0: 0x00000001a9cb8e08 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x1a9cb8e08 <+0>: ret    
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_reportToDebugger:
    0x1a9cb8e0c <+0>: b      0x1a9cb8e08               ; _swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_shouldReportFatalErrorsToDebugger:
    0x1a9cb8e10 <+0>: adrp   x8, 346593
    0x1a9cb8e14 <+4>: ldrb   w0, [x8, #0x7c8]
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
Lost connection to device.
```

For reference the assert that fails is the `guard let sink = conntext.characteristicValueUpdateSink` line in the swift code block:

```
  onCharacteristicValueUpdate: papply(weak: self) {
                context, central, characteristic, value, error in
                guard let sink = context.characteristicValueUpdateSink
                else { assert(false); return }

                let message = CharacteristicValueInfo.with {
                    $0.characteristic = CharacteristicAddress.with {
                        $0.characteristicUuid = Uuid.with { $0.data = characteristic.id.data }
                        $0.serviceUuid = Uuid.with { $0.data = characteristic.serviceID.data }
                        $0.deviceID = characteristic.peripheralID.uuidString
                    }
                    if let value = value {
                        $0.value = value
                    }
                    if let error = error {
                        $0.failure = GenericFailure.with {
                            $0.code = Int32(CharacteristicValueUpdateFailure.unknown.rawValue)
                            $0.message = "\(error)"
                        }
                    }
                }
                sink.add(.success(message))
            }
```

The assert is doing what it is supposed to do but I cannot figure out what I'm not doing right in the way I set up and make the call to `subscribeToCharacteristic`. I suspect it may be the way the `Stream` is set up and not getting passed down properly to the swift code since the `assert` seems to be guarding against a null Sink? But I really don't have enough experience.

Help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: hi, did you managed solved this?
i am having the same issue with BT module HC-04b

Comment: Not solved but did find out that it is a known issue and has a workaround.

Comment: https://github.com/PhilipsHue/flutter_reactive_ble/issues/137

Comment: #137 is the original issue and #251 is a duplicate